# Retrofit 2.0 + GSON Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit 2.0 in my app. Everything was quite good, but when I started request with no args, GSON returns:

```
Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface
com.example.project.API.GetPhones. Register an InstanceCreator
with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
```

Here's my API interface:

```
public interface GetPhones {
    @GET("phones.php")
    Call<ArrayList<GetPhones>> getPhones();
}
```

and model class:

```
public class GetPhones {
    int id;
    char[] iso;
    String name;
    String phone_1;
    String phone_2;
    String phone_3;
}
```

and code in fragment:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
         .baseUrl(URL_API)
         .client(SSLSuppressClient.trustcert())
         .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
         .build();
GetPhones getPhonesInfo = retrofit.create(GetPhones.class);
Call<GetPhones> call = getPhonesInfo.getPhones();
call.enqueue(new Callback<GetPhones>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<GetPhones> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failure!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("LOG", t.getMessage());
                }
    });
```

I've tried to make no-args constructor for GetPhones.class, but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the same name for interface (`interface GetPhones`) and model class (`class GetPhones`).

I think you are using interface in this line:

```
Call<ArrayList<GetPhones>> getPhones();
```

But it should be your model class. Check import section for it or rename model class to be sure that you are not mixing it.

Answer (score 53):

If anyone in 2019 comes across this and is using Kotlin, coroutines and at least Retrofit 2.6.0, returning a `Call<MyObject>` instance while the api method is `suspended`, produces the same error message, which is a little confusing.

The solution is to replace `Call<MyObject>` with `MyObject` in the interface definition, and remove `?.execute()?.body()` (or equivalent) at the call site.

**EDIT:**

The reason I think most people will stumble across this is that they want to wrap their suspended Retrofit responses in something to handle errors in a seamless way.

There is an issue on this [located here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3193), perhaps Retrofit will deal with this in the future. I ended up using the [kind solution provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56483235/how-to-create-a-call-adapter-for-suspending-functions-in-retrofit/57816819#57816819).

Comment: Thank you so much. I was facing the same issue. This worked!!

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes. Thank you!

Comment: Hello Daniel I was using a convertor to Call<T> to ResultWrapper<T> and I was using the execute method, now how it works? Since I do not have the execute method

Comment: You're my hero, pal!

Comment: I was frustrated by the lack of access to the full response for error handling, then I spotted in the release note (Retrofit's docs are not great) to return `Response<T>` . This seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks @SimonFeatherstone! 
Change return `Call<T>` to `Response<T>` works here!

Answer (score 1):

This was really helpful. I had the same issue and it worked by replacing `Call<MyObject>` with `MyObject` in the interface where we write the function for the API call request followed by removing `.enque` at the call site.