# Custom response/error handler for retrofit 2.6

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have the following class:

```
interface API
{
    @GET("/data.json")
    suspend fun fetchData() : MyResponse

    companion object
    {
        private val BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/"

        fun create(): MyAPI
        {
            val gson = GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                .create()

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory( GsonConverterFactory.create( gson ) )
                .baseUrl( BASE_URL )
                .build()

            return retrofit.create( MyAPI::class.java )
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling it the following way:

```
val data = StadiumAPI.create().fetchData()
Log.d( "gotdata", data.toString() )
```

Everything works great, but now I want to handle errors, I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

```
    Var response = StadiumAPI.create().fetchData()

    when( response.state )
    {
        Success       -> doSomethingWithTheData( response.data )
        Error         -> showError( response.error )
        Processing    -> showSpinner()
    }
```

The main problem is that not only I would need to handle success/error (based on the HTTP status code and if GSON conversion was successful) but also handle exceptions (like network issues) and pass down them as Error to the response state as well as keep the automatic conversion with GSON without handling it manually.

I'm completely lost where to go from here. As far as I understood I need to create a custom data type in the retrofit response API which will "accept" the response and then I could manipulate its properties to produce the code structure above. Could you please point me in the right direction where should I go from here? Thanks!

----------- EDIT -------------------------------------------

I found out I can do what I'm trying the following way:

```
interface API
{
    @GET("/data.json")
    suspend fun fetchData() : ApiResponse<MyResponse>
    ....
}
```

And here is the **ApiResponse**:

```
sealed class ApiResponse<T> {
    companion object {
        fun <T> create(response: Response<T>): ApiResponse<T> {
            Log.d( "networkdebug", "success: " + response.body().toString() )
            return if(response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d( "networkdebug", "success: " + response.body().toString() )
                val body = response.body()
                // Empty body
                if (body == null || response.code() == 204) {
                    ApiSuccessEmptyResponse()
                } else {
                    ApiSuccessResponse(body)
                }
            } else {
                val msg = response.errorBody()?.string()
                Log.d( "networkdebug", "error: " + msg.toString() )
                val errorMessage = if(msg.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    response.message()
                } else {
                    msg
                }
                ApiErrorResponse(errorMessage ?: "Unknown error")
            }
        }
    }
}

class ApiSuccessResponse<T>(val data: T): ApiResponse<T>()
class ApiSuccessEmptyResponse<T>: ApiResponse<T>()
class ApiErrorResponse<T>(val errorMessage: String): ApiResponse<T>()
```

But for whatever reason the CompanionObject within the ApiResponse is not triggering at all, any hints on what I could be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You need custom call adapter factory

Comment: https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/util/LiveDataCallAdapter.kt

Comment: https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/util/LiveDataCallAdapterFactory.kt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56483235/how-to-create-a-call-adapter-for-suspending-functions-in-retrofit