# I got " Error Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class CLASSNAME" with Parcalize

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I am using **@Parcelize** to create parcable model with kotlin

```
@Parcelize
data class GymPackage(
    val id: Int?,
    val name: String?,
    val description: String?,
    val price: Int?,
    val duration: Int?,
    @SerializedName("discount_precentage")
    val discountPrecentage: Int?,
    @SerializedName("price_after_discount")
    val priceAfterDiscount: Double?,
    @SerializedName("gym_id")
    val gymId: Int?

) : Parcelable
```

i got this error `Error Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class com.inova.algym.datalayer.remote.responses.GymPackage. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.`

koltin version :: `1.3.61`

Tried this but not solve the problem

- [retrofit-2-0-gson-unable-to-invoke-no-args-constructor-for-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749752/retrofit-2-0-gson-unable-to-invoke-no-args-constructor-for-interface)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrofit 2.0 + GSON Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749752/retrofit-2-0-gson-unable-to-invoke-no-args-constructor-for-interface)

Comment: no does not work with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type this in Gradle

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin-noarg"
```

Comment: Could u please, provide what is problem, reason , and why u think your answer will solve it?